# Analogous Properties in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I was wondering if there is such a way to duplicate the `wrap_content` XML property in Kivy.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
|                     REALLY LARGE TITLE                      |  
|                                                             |
|                            Play                             |
|                                                             |
|                           Scores                            |
|                                                             |
|                           About                             |
|                                                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, I can't use a `BoxLayout` because it can't account for the large title among the buttons.

Comment: Can you explain what behaviour you want and what your problem with a BoxLayout + Labels (ideally with an example)? I don't know what the wrap_content XML property does.

Comment: Basically in Kivy, I can not seem to duplicate a dynamic `BoxLayout` size. In standard Android programming, `wrap_content` makes the parent layout stretch to the size of it's contained widgets. I can't do this in Kivy because I have to specify a fixed size for the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give the buttons/labels specific sizes, you can use a GridLayout with one column and give it a kv rule `height: self.minimum_height`. It will then automatically adjust its height to match the sum of heights of its children, which you must set manually (and give them `size_hint_y: None`.

Comment: The buttons should be 200 by 30 pixels.

Comment: Are you saying that because you don't understand how to set their size?

Comment: I know how to set the size with the `size` attribute but the buttons expand to the size of the float layout. Do you have an email to which I can send code?

Comment: Paste your code here, that's the point of stackoverflow. But anyway, it sounds like your problem isn't the boxlayout but some FloatLayout elsewhere?